# Best place to store application content

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdocumentdirectory

I have application, that operates with large amount of data (basically images), that downloaded from our server and should be available without internet connection.

I used to store them in `<Application_Home>/Library/Caches` directory, but after iOS update process all of them was deleted. This behaviour is unacceptable for me and now I'm looking for better place where I can store data and be sure they will not deleted by the system.

What is the best place to store this kind of data?

Comment: what about the `Documents` folder? was any particular reason why you have not stored anything in there?

Comment: Yes, apple say: "Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app, such as user-generated content."

Comment: you just quoted the point here: _"Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app"_, your post's first sentence is about _"(...) large amount of data (basically images), that downloaded from our server (...)"_, so the question is, **can those images be recreated by your app?**. if your answer is _no_, then there is no reason why you could not use the `Documents` folder... if your answer is _yes_, you don't need to store those images anywhere, because your app can recreate those in runtime...

Comment: The answer is "yes, images can be recreated", but one of main goals is to make this data available without internet connection, because user will want to have access to it rather than download 300+ Mb each time or when it suddenly missed.

Comment: if the images **can be recreated** by the app in runtime without any external resources, you do not need to store them, because according to your answer (i.e. _yes_) the application can recreate them anytime. I'm just wondering whether you understood the Apple statement correctly... no offense but it seems you may misunderstand it – because if the images are coming from an external source (i.e. _your sever_) the application is not able to (i.e. _cannot_) recreate them therefore you can use the `Documents` folder to store them.

Comment: Hmm... Honestly, I thought "recreate" includes "download and save". I now understand what you mean. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The caches directory is what the name implies, as cache. Caches can be emptied and you should indeed re download the images. The documents directory is a better place to store these images, but you should store then with the [skip iCould backup key](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html) on the file.

Just a small tip, always use either [`URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:) or [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains)

Comment: But apple say that only user data or data that can't be recreated should stored in Documents directory. I pretty sure, that app will be rejected if I'll try to store data there.
Hmm... What about <Application_Home>/Library/Application Support directory?

Comment: I've saved many data there that is reproducible, but as long as you add the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Only data in the documents directory isn't deleted by iOS:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
```

Data in the documents are synchronized with the iCloud. If you have a lot of them you need to disable this option:

```
[urlOfImage setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
```